# ASP.NET MVC - Some way of calling an ActionView from an Void or an int

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The reason is not to check if the account exist. I already have the [Authorize] on the top of the controller. This code below is only a test done to see if it was possible call the RedirectToAction or something like from a void or from a int int this case.

I have a public int GetPersonCode on a controller, and I wanto to put something like this:

```
public int GetPersonCode()
{
    try
    {
        //This is setted on login
        return (int)Session["PersonCode"];
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log(e);
        //Some way to redirect to the login
    }
}
```

There is any way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Whether you *can* and whether you *should* are two different answers. You should already have redirected the user to the login page long before this method is going to be called, usually this is done with the `Authorize` attribute for example.

Comment: I know. I have the [Authorize] on top of the controller, just want to know if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to check if an account exists, or if a user is logged in (regardless of which) and you simply want to redirect the user to another page if there is an error, you can do as follows:

Change `int GetPersonCode()` to `bool TryGetPersonCode(ref int value)`. It will look something like this:

```
public bool TryGetPersonCode(ref int value)
{
    try
    {
        //This is setted on login
        value = (int)Session["PersonCode"];
        return true; // Success
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log(e);
        return false; // Failed
    }
}
```

Then in the method where you are calling `GetPersonCode()` do this instead:

```
int value; // This value will be changed inside 'TryGetPersonCode()'
if (TryGetPersonCode(ref value))
{
    // Success, do whatever you need with 'value'
}
else
{
    // Failed, 'value' will still be null
    // Here you can do your redirect
    RedirectToAction("Login Failed Action");
}
```

This type of functionality is common in the .NET Framework. The boolean return indicates whether or not it worked. If it returns true, your `value` variable will have been set within the method. Otherwise, the `value` variable will not have been set and the method will have returned false, indicating something went wrong.

I hope this helps, good luck with whatever you are working on :)

Comment: How Shimmy tells I make a mistake not telling the full reason for the need. I do not need to check the login. I just want to check if it's possible call a view from another thing who is not a ActionView.
But thanks for the answer.

Comment: You can always return a view from another method and then use that return value in your ActionView method (both methods will return an ActionView). If you need a code example I can edit my answer. Otherwise, please mark one of our answers correct.

Comment: Actually the idea would call a void or something that did not return an action view and for a X reason or need this void had to call a different view she could somehow, but from what I saw, do not exist a method to force redirection from the void, only from the action view.

Comment: I agree with what you are saying, there is not a way to do what you are asking. The only way to return an ActionView would be to return it in the controller method. I believe my answer is about as close as one can get while still using good practice. Remember, marking an answer correct also gains you reputation!

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit unclear what you're asking, but if you want to allow the action for authenticated users only, you should annotate your action or even the entire controller with the [`Authorize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute) attribute and MVC will automatically redirect the user to the authentication page in order for the current session to be able to access the action.

You can also specify roles with the `Authorize` attribute, via its `Roles` property.

**Update**

If you want to open a different view, use [`RedirectToAction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction) when needed.

Comment: I know. I have the [Authorize] on top of the controller, just want to know if it is possible to call an actionview from a void or a int on this sample.
Sorry for my bad english and thanks for the answer.

Comment: But this only works if you are in a ActionResult and return the RedirectToAction, right?

Comment: You should have that method you're talking about as `IActionResult` as well.

Comment: @AirtonGomesdeLima You ask your question "can you do it" but neglect to tell us the technical reason you require this? Seems like you could eliminate all this confusion with some clarification on your original post.

Comment: Currently there is no real need for it, was only a question of curiosity.